# wordpress how to manage web and mobile sites with one database

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I want to build a web site in wordpress. A web version like mysite.com and a mobile version like m.mysite.com. I am thinking that will it do able in wordpress because wordpress save domain name in database.

mysite.com/m will be possible but the requirement is to go with m.mysite.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach in this helped me: http://www.phillipadsmith.com/2011/11/note-to-self-a-simple-way-to-accomplish-mobile-site-redirection-using-mod-rewrite.html

However, proper creation of templates and css will really make the need redundant.